how to get ride of this bot, on marketing SEO & search / search term
im been trying to block the bots, i added google recaptcha but impossible. please help


Simply add below lines in root .htaccess file
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (crawl|Ahrefs|Semrush|BLEX|Yandex|Seznam|Dotbot|CCbot|Curl|BaiDu|MJ12|Sogou|CFNetwork|Python|WordPress|WebFilter|Nutch|Exabot|HTTrack|Barkrowler|facebookexternalhit) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Go-http-client/1.1 [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]


i added it yesterday night and i checked today again and still the same thing. im thinking to update to magento 2.4.3 but im scare because its hard to install elasticsearch. any clean way that i can install it without problem?

That bot seems to try to get into your database. I would try to block it on server level. So you could maybe block it with a firewall on your server or depending on, if you are using apache2 or nginx, block it with .htaccess or nginx config.
You need the IP of the bot for that. So have a look at your server logs to find the IP address.

do you think if i update magento 2 version Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1 to higher will help?

It should help regarding security, but it wont help against random bots.
The 2.3 version ran out of support some years ago and will not receive any updates...

You should check apache access logs and check for new bots name
